# How to assign column name from variable

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to assign a value to a table column. The column selected needs to be based on a variable. How do you do this?

If @language = "german" than I want to assign @new_word.german = string

```
@new_word = Word.new
@new_word.german = string
@new_word.save
```

So how would I assign .german using @language? @new_word.@language :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = "german"
@new_word.send("#{x}=", "some value")
@new_word[x] = "some value" # may end up skipping overrides/callbacks, etc though. check the docs.
```

Comment: I think there is a random "=" in your send.

Comment: No. That is intentional. You're invoking the 'german=' method.

Comment: Gotcha, does send stop a loop? My loop seems to only run once with this inside it.

Comment: What does the @new_word[x] = "some value" do? The send seems to insert what I need already. Thanks

Comment: @DDDD send does not stop a loop. See here for docs on `[]=` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D